# Use JQuery Datepicker

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

How can I use jQuery Datepicker in a web page that uses an iframe? Where should I link css and script reference?

Comment: same way you would use it in an html page. iFrame or not, the javascript is relative to the file using the date picker.

Comment: Edited out the references to ColdFusion, because your question is about the resulting HTML, not the server side language used to generate the HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There would be no difference when using an iframe or a non-framed page.

Assuming you have a JS folder for your javascript in your root folder and a CSS folder in your root folder with the appropriate files copied there.  This would be a basic example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/css/datepicker.css"></script>
<script>


$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#yourDateField").datepicker();
});
</script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<form>
  <label for="yourDateField">Date Field</label>
  <input type="text" name="yourDateField" id="yourDateField">

</form>


</body>
</html>
```